# Need to convert multiple vectors into matrix in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a matrix with many columns. I want to take each column and convert into smaller matrix and append them to make a new matrix

Like below is the given data

```
A1   B1   C1   
1    9    17   
2    10   18   
3    11   19   
4    12   20   
5    13   21   
6    14   22   
7    15   23   
8    16   24
```

It should be changed to

```
1    5
2    6
3    7
4    8
9    13
10   14
11   15
12   16
17   21
18   22
19   23
20   24
```

I have given a small example. But I do have huge number of columns in my data. I would like to know how can we achieve this by writing a function/loop

Comment: What is the logic to `convert into smaller matrix` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looping through the column, convert the column to a `matrix` with 'n' rows i.e. 4 rows and 2 columns, `rbind` the `list` elements to create a `matrix`

```
# if the input is data.frame
do.call(rbind, lapply(df1, matrix, ncol=2, nrow = 4)) 
#       [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    5
# [2,]    2    6
# [3,]    3    7
# [4,]    4    8
# [5,]    9   13
# [6,]   10   14
# [7,]   11   15
# [8,]   12   16
# [9,]   17   21
#[10,]   18   22
#[11,]   19   23
#[12,]   20   24
```

Note that if the input is matrix, it can be converted to `data.frame` using `as.data.frame` (for the `lapply`)

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
```

The `lapply` loops through the columns of the dataset and returns a `list` of `vector`s

```
lapply(df1, I)
#$A1
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

#$B1
#[1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

#$C1
#[1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

These `vector`s are changed to `matrix` (a matrix is a vector with `dim` attribute) by calling `matrix` and specifying the number of rows (`nrow`), number of columns (`ncol`)

```
lapply(df1, matrix, nrow = 4, ncol = 2)
#$A1
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    5
#[2,]    2    6
#[3,]    3    7
#[4,]    4    8

#$B1
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    9   13
#[2,]   10   14
#[3,]   11   15
#[4,]   12   16

#$C1
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   17   21
#[2,]   18   22
#[3,]   19   23
#[4,]   20   24
```

Now, we have a `list` of matrices, which is then binded together with `rbind` (row binding) to create a single `matrix`

Wrap it with `as.data.frame` (if a data.frame is needed)

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(df1, matrix, ncol=2, nrow = 4)))
```

---

If the input is a matrix

```
a1 <- array(m1, c(4, 2, 3))
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(dim(a1)[3]), function(i) a1[,,i]))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    5
# [2,]    2    6
# [3,]    3    7
# [4,]    4    8
# [5,]    9   13
# [6,]   10   14
# [7,]   11   15
# [8,]   12   16
# [9,]   17   21
#[10,]   18   22
#[11,]   19   23
#[12,]   20   24
```

NOTE: It is more general when there are more rows and columns

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My input is matrix indeed. Could you please brief me what you have done on the matrix lapply function. I want to understand better before I code in

Comment: @Newbie_Python  If you have a input matrix, in the first code, wrap with `as.data.frame(df1)` and then use `lapply` it would work.  What happened is that when we use `lapply`, it is looping through columns (of data.frame) as a `vector`.  By calling `matrix`, we created a dimension attribute of number of rows and columns

Comment: I did try the first one. That does not work for me. But your second solution works perfectly for me.
a1 <- array(m1, c(4, 2, 3))
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(dim(a1)[3]), function(i) a1[,,i]))
But I am curious what seq_len does and what argument 3 denotes

Comment: @Newbie_Python   I updated the post.  Please try it after converting to `data.frame`. With the array call, with 3 dim attributes, it is a 3D array..  So, we loop through the sequence of the 3rd dimension index to subset the array into a `list` and the `rbind` it

Answer (score 2):

You can just `cbind` the top rows and bottom rows:

```
> cbind(c(x[1 : (nrow(x)/2), ]), c(x[(nrow(x)/2 + 1) : nrow(x), ]))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    5
 [2,]    2    6
 [3,]    3    7
 [4,]    4    8
 [5,]    9   13
 [6,]   10   14
 [7,]   11   15
 [8,]   12   16
 [9,]   17   21
[10,]   18   22
[11,]   19   23
[12,]   20   24
```

, where `x` is the input matrix.

Comment: simple and straightforward, though the order operations and parenthesis can be irritating. `bind_cols` works too.